# Preserve original dict order rather than random?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

If you look at the following code:

```
examples = {"Main 1": "blabla", "Main 2": "test", "Main 3": "ya", "Main 4": "ha", "Main 5": "no", "Main 6": "blabla", "Main 7": "test", "Main 8": "ya", "Main 9": "ha", "Main 10": "no", "Main 11": "blabla", "Main 12": "test", "Main 13": "ya", "Main 14": "ha", "Main 15": "no", "Main 16": "boo", "Main 17": "blabla", "Main 18": "test", "Main 19": "ya", "Main 20": "ha", "Main None": "None",}

for example in examples.keys():
    print example
```

It prints the following:

```
Main 1
Main 14
Main 3
Main 2
Main 5
Main 4
Main 7
Main 6
Main 9
Main 8
Main None
Main 12
Main 19
Main 17
Main 18
Main 16
Main 13
Main 15
Main 20
Main 11
Main 10
```

How do I make it preserver the dict order so that it goes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7...etc

Comment: Python dictionaries *are not ordered*. You cannot preserve the initial ordering; use `collections.OrderedDict()` instead.

Comment: the alternative is to sort your keys; a natural sort would be required though.

Comment: A quick search for "sorted dictionary python" or "ordered dictionary python" returns https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html. Please refer to "Search, and research" section of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Last but not least, the `.keys()` call is redundant; you can loop directly over a dictionary and still get keys:  `for example in examples:`.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary dictionaries are constructed from a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) and do not preserve ordering. Use `OrderedDict` from the standard library `collections` module instead.